# Observing changes in UIDocumentState in swift

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, observers

I am struggling to find the correct syntax for adding an observer that will monitor changes to documents stored on the iCloud.

I managed to find the following for observing key-value-store changes:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.ubiquitousKeyDidChange), name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.didChangeExternallyNotification, object: keyStore)
```

But cant find the correct syntax for document stateChangedNotifications.

I have searched for a week now but without any luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocument/1619945-statechangednotification

Comment: I did look at the documentation but I just can't work out how to implement it. ie the correct syntax for creating the observer.